# jQuery UI tooltip not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show a tooltip popup when clicking on a date in the UI Datepicker:

```
(function($) {

    var events = [
        { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("09/16/2013") },
        { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("09/17/2013") },
        { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("09/18/2013") }
    ];

    //console.log(events[1]);
    $("#my-calendar" ).datepicker({


    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            //console.log(event.Date.valueOf() );
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },

    onSelect: function(dateText) {

            var date,
                selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
                i = 0,
                event = null;

            /* Determine if the user clicked an event: */
            while (i < events.length && !event) {
                date = events[i].Date;

                if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                    event = events[i];
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (event) {
                /* If the event is defined, perform some action here; show a tooltip, navigate to a URL, etc. */
                var day = new Date(event.Date).getDate().toString();
                $("a.ui-state-default:contains("+day+")").tooltip({content:'yay'}); //selector definitely returns the relevant day



            }
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

However, no tooltip appears when I click on the date. The tooltip eventually needs to contain links to events.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/codecowboy/TW6bn/1/)

Comment: could you set this up on jsfiddle, otherwise its hard to help...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/codecowboy/TW6bn/1/

Comment: Can't you use the beforeShowDay third parameter to show a tooltip? like http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/TW6bn/2/

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward you can but its limited and I want a larger custom tooltip containing links, probably also with a close button. Also, I'm trying to get it to appear on click not hover.

Comment: It seems that this simply doesn't work. The calendar doesn't work together with tooltips, at least for the date fields. .Tooltip uses the "title" attribute of an element usually, calendar simply controls all calendar elements and overrules any action done by tooltip.

Comment: Thanks - if you expand to an answer I will accept.